# Custom printout of pdf slides using LaTeX as compiler

Tags: pdf, alignment, slideshow

I am a student and always print my slides with three slides per page using the functionality of adobe acrobat reader. It suits my needs, however I would like to adjust it more to my own liking. Currently the printed slides are 3 slides stacked on each other centered on the page. What I would like to do is have these three slides per page lined up where you would bind the book. So from page to page it would alter from left aligned, right aligned, left aligned, right aligned. So I have more space to write notes next to the slides. I do not want lines to write, blank is perfect for me. Also I want to have a thin black border around each slide.

So how can I change a pdf document containing all slides into a new pdf document where three slides are stacked on top of each other and aligned at the binding with a thin black border around each slide?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way to do it and it fills all my needs. I hope fellow students may also benefit from this superior way of printing slides.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-, scale=0.9, nup=1x3, frame, delta = 0 5, offset = -35mm 0mm]{example-image-ducks.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings with the community! Just a tip: if you want to make it easier for your fellow students to quickly test your code to see if it is what they are looking for, you can use an example document available to everybody as part of their tex distribution. For example something from the `mwe` package, or for a bit more fun, `\includepdf[pages=-, scale=0.95, nup=1x3, frame, delta = 0 5, offset = -40mm 0mm]{example-image-duck}`